# JSF f:ajax onevent not reading bean value

Tags: javascript, jsf, javabeans

I have an AdminBean that has a loggedIn boolean which is set after a query from an onclick:

```
    <h:commandButton rendered="#{!adminBean.loggedIn}" styleClass="moreButtonAsText" id="adminLoginAsText" value="Login" action="#{adminBean.logIn}">
      <f:ajax render="detailsBox adminForm" execute="@form" onevent="onevent"/>
    </h:commandButton>

  </h:form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function onevent(e){
    if(e.status=='success') {
      alert(#{adminBean.loggedIn});
    } 
    if(e.status=='complete') {
      alert(#{adminBean.loggedIn});
    } 
  }
</script>
```

I need this because I want to do a different javascript thing based on if the user successfully logged in or not.  The command button is first clicked (obviously) and then logged in is set to true.  I have this explicitly in my AdminBean class:

```
public boolean isLoggedIn() {
    System.out.println(loggedIn);
    return loggedIn;
}
```

Originally I had the onevent all nested like `onevent="#{adminBean.loggedIn} ? yesFunction : noFunction`, but this did not work.  So I read around and found 
http://fyhao.com/2010/05/computer-and-it/java/java-server-faces/jsf-2-fajax-why-execute-onevent-three-times/
So I decided to split it up into an inline function, but this still didn't work.
Then I decided to go with what I posted above, except with clear alert statements as to what the JavaScript thinks the value is (and my printlines to see if they agree...)

The Java console, by the first alert (which is `e.status=='complete'`), prints out a lot of falses at first, and then a lot of trues.
The JavaScript alerts false.

I then clear the console and click ok on the alert.  The console then prints *nothing*, and the second alert is called, still false.  So my JavaScript fails.

Now one other weird thing I noticed... the AdminBean is session scoped.  When I press enter in the address bar again, no matter what I do the JavaScript will alert true... even though the renders still work properly (stuff that should only render when logged in is not shown, even though the JavaScript alerts `true`).

What the heck is going on?

If you need more information/code, ask.

**Edit #1:**

When I said above that I tried `onevent="#{adminBean.loggedIn} ? yesFunction : noFunction`,
I also tried `onevent="#{adminBean.loggedIn} ? yesFunction : noFunction`.  I realize I may be missing quotes/apostrophes on those functions, but before I solve that issue I'd like to fix the adminBean.loggedIn issue.

**Edit #2:**

See the selected answer;  I was working on this solution and then the answer basically confirmed my results.

```
<h:form id="javascriptHack">
  <h:form id="hiddenJS" rendered="#{adminBean.loggedIn}" >
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
        (#{adminBean.loggedIn}) ? slowCloseAdminPanel() : adminPanelLeftOpen();
      });
    </script>
  </h:form>
</h:form>
```

This might be a hackish way to do it, but it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your ajax request does not update the script. It will still hold the initial values. You could put the script inside `<h:form>`. This should work.

Comment: Originally I had `onevent="#{adminBean.loggedIn} ? first : second", which was in the f:ajax, which is re-rendering the form it is inside of.  I don't know why that wouldn't work.  However... I was working and now am done testing something that is basically exactly what you recommended (before I saw your comment).  I'll edit my code to post the solution.  Why did the first method not work, though?